# Hibernate persisting an Object member

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Is there any way to persist an Entity member of type java.lang.Object ?

lets say i have an entity DynamicProperty which has a members

```
private String name;
private Object value;
```

Value can be of several types basically non complex ones (String, Boolean, Integer, Decimal, Enum...)

is there any way doing it ? and what the DB(Oracle) column type should be .

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution...as my my Object can be defined as several limited types, basic type i flagged the Object as serializable DB column as BLOB and it worked.

```
@Type(type = "serializable")
private Object value;
```

does any one knows regarding the performance if this ? or any other issues that can occur..

Comment: The performance will be worse then simply transforming the value to a String. But the main problem is that you won't be able to do anything with your data except from Java code. Even looking at the data using your favorite database client won't help you much, because it will be stored in a Java proprietary binary format instead of being stored as a readable string. I would use a column to hold the type of the object (Double, Boolean, etc.) and a column to store the string representation of the object.

Answer (score 0):

If they're basic types, you can always try to store them as Strings and then cast them to right classes in your getter.

There's also another option - you can create a class which will hold value type and will have fields of necessary types, only one being set though. Something like

```
class Foo
{
    Integer a;
    Double b;
    String c;
    int type;

    //getters and setters

    public Object getObject()
    {
        if (type == 1)
            return a;
        else if (type == 2)
            return b;
        return c;
    }
}
```

It's a bit of a workaround, but it should work. I think it isn't possible to persist an Object as abstract.

Also, take a look at the `@Embedded` annotation, it may help.

Comment: i didn't understood your first suggestion, if i store them as VARCHAR, you mean the java property should be typed as String ? how will the casting work when you don't know the type ?

Comment: If we're talking about Integers and Double, it's simple - just use `Integer.parseInt()` and in case of expection `Double.parseDouble()`. If you wan to use other types, you could store the first byte of the string as type byte, e.g. `int 7` would be `I7`, `double 3.14` - `D3.14`, `String foo` - `Sfoo` etc. You could also have another field which would hold the type of the object, like in my code example and base your casting on it.